# Standard terminology for the "quotient of a quotient"

Tags: number-theory, terminology

Let $n$ and $m$ be integers.  One can write
$$
n = mq_0 + r_0
$$ where $0\leq r_0 < m$; the $q_0$ term in the right-hand side is the "quotient". One could then write
$$
q_0 = mq_1 + r_1
$$ where $0\leq r_1 < m$.  What is the standard terminology for the $q_1$  term (the "quotient of the quotient")?  Proceeding inductively, if we define
$$
q_i = mq_{i+1} + r_i
$$ where $0\leq r_i < m$ for all $i\geq 0$, then what is the terminology for the terms $q_0,q_1,q_2,\ldots,$?

I am $not$ applying the Euclidean algorithm here.

Comment: I'm afraid you're making some mistakes in applying the Euclidean algorithm, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Procedure

Comment: I am not applying the Euclidean algorithm (see my comment below).

Comment: so $q_k =n \mod m^{k+1}$

Answer (score 1):

It's the algorithm to write the digits of the number *n* in the numbersystem with base *m* I think. The $r_k$ are then the digits, but I do not know a name for the $q_k$. $q_0 = \lfloor n / m \rfloor$ ,$q_1 = \lfloor q_0 / m \rfloor$ ...
Example: if $m=10$ One could ask: if $n=1234321$ what is the name for the part $q_0=123432$ ? or for the part $q_2=1234$?
It's not exactly "the leading digits", the best I could name it were " $q_k$ is the *floor-function of $n / m^{k+1}$* "

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that
there is any standard term.
These are the quotients
in the Euclidean algorithm.

You might see terms such as
"first quotient",
"n-th quotient",
or
"final quotient",
but I think that
is about it.

Comment: These quotients do not align with the Euclidean algorithm.  When computing the $\gcd$ of $m$ and $n$, one doesn't compute the quotient with respect to $m$ at each iteration. Thanks for the response.